# MultiChoiceAdapter for ActionbarCompat NoSuchMethodException: startActionMode

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar-compat, multichoiceitems

I'm using [MultiChoiceAdapter](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter) for ActionBarCompat and I'm having `NoSuchMethodException: startActionMode`. My gradle installation is  `compile 'com.github.manuelpeinado.multichoiceadapter:multichoiceadapter-abc:3.0.0'` that's all.

Logcat

```
 2755-2755/ W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: startActionMode [interface android.support.v7.view.ActionMode$Callback]
2755-2755/W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
01-12 10:59:22.604    2755-2755/W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
01-12 10:59:22.608    2755-2755/W/System.err﹕ at com.manuelpeinado.multichoiceadapter.extras.actionbarcompat.MultiChoiceAdapterHelper.startActionMode(MultiChoiceAdapterHelper.java:37)
01-12 10:59:22.608    2755-2755/W/System.err﹕ at com.manuelpeinado.multichoiceadapter.MultiChoiceAdapterHelperBase.checkItem(MultiChoiceAdapterHelperBase.java:115)
01-12 10:59:22.612    2755-2755/W/System.err﹕ at com.manuelpeinado.multichoiceadapter.MultiChoiceAdapterHelperBase.setItemChecked(MultiChoiceAdapterHelperBase.java:103)
01-12 10:59:22.612    2755-2755/W/System.err﹕ at com.manuelpeinado.multichoiceadapter.MultiChoiceAdapterHelperBase.onItemLongClick(MultiChoiceAdapterHelperBase.java:205)
01-12 10:59:22.616    2755-2755/W/System.err﹕ at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2854)
```

I've followed everything the sample folder told me too and had no problems with Eclipse version of it. Any fixes for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in the 3.1.0 version, you have to use `compile 'com.github.manuelpeinado.multichoiceadapter:multichoiceadapter-abc:3.1.0'`

If you check [this commit](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter/commit/f4e41f9cee0f47702141164dcb8bc2edff4d9b6e) you can see that he was still using startActionMode instead of startSupportActionMode